# URL-путь в качестве параметра

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Использую JSP и Tomcat.
Нужно заменить вызов `http://localhost:8084/LDB/?user=drt` на `http://localhost:8084/LDB/drt`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То что вы спрашиваете называется переопределение адреса (URL rewrite). Добиться этого можно по крайней мере двумя путями:

- Создать фильтр или взять готовый например [здесь](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)
- Настроить rewriteURL на прокси сервере если таковой планируется ([Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), [nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)  или другой)